# Calculate the sum of input values in the last column of table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tying to sum up the dynamic input values in the last column of my table. If I hard code the number values then the calculation works just fine. If I input the values my self using a  I get NaN

Ive used

My html table is added upon load and the rows are added as needed via a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <table id='table' border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>RO#</th>
          <th>Work</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>615235</td>
          <td>lof, rotate</td>
          <!-- <td>23</td> -->
          <td><input type="number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6154879</td>
          <td>engine, trans</td>
          <!-- <td>23</td> -->
          <td><input typ="number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6158978</td>
          <td>rotate, serp belt, timing belt</td>
          <!-- <td>23</td> -->
          <td><input type="number" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <br>

      <button onclick='calculate()'>Calculate</button>

      <script>
        function calculate() {
          let tbl = document.getElementById('table'),
              sumVal = 0;

          for (let i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(tbl.rows[i].cells[2].input);
          }

          console.log(sumVal);
        }
      </script>


    </body>
  </html>
```

I get `NaN` when using the `<td><input type="number or type="text"><td>` code

Comment: When I hard code the numbered values I use .innerHTML instead of .input in the script and that works fine. I cant seem to figure out the how to calculate the number values when the user inputs them.

Comment: I think the problem is that your code that attempts to get the value of the `<input>` elements is wrong. You could use a single `document.querySelector()` call to get all the inputs. For each one, you have to get the "value" property and that's what you'd pass to `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `input` property does not exist in `tbl.rows[i].cells[2]`. Honestly, I don't know if it's possible to get the input values from Table cells Collection that you're trying to utilize.

I suggest this approach, using `querySelectorAll` in which we specify the inputs we'd like to get data from:

```
function calculate() {
    let tbl = document.querySelectorAll("table input[type='number']"),
        sumVal = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < tbl.length; i++) {
      sumVal += Number(tbl[i].value);
    }
    console.log(sumVal);
  }
```

Comment: Thanx this does help. Im getting numbers for my total now but it seems to be always skipping over the second row not matter how many rows I have. So my total is wrong in the the end.

Comment: There's a typo I forgot to mention: `<td><input typ="number" /></td>` - there should be `type`, not `typ`. That's the reason why the second row is being skipped.

Comment: Oh boy I cant believe I missed that. Thanks so much this is working just fine now. This will work perfectly for what im doing. Thanx again.